# How to detect the number of ongoing calls on Android

Tags: android

I'm looking for a synchronous way of checking the number of active phone calls on Android.

When searching google, folks mention the [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) a lot  but the only method I see for this purpose is `getCallState` which seems return only the current call state. I assume this is for the active call. Others use I have found is about attaching a listener and then waiting and counting.

This is no good for me, as I'm on phonegap and just want a method I can call which gives me an overview of the current calls. Note that I want to know, if there is more than one call active. For once, it looks like the iPhone ios api has exactly this in [currentCalls](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/CTCallCenter/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009604) method.

It hard for me to beleive, that Android doesn't have such a method. I just can't seem to find it.

Anyone? Thanks!

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#listen%28android.telephony.PhoneStateListener,%20int%29

Answer (score 0):

```
**AndroidManifest.xml**.


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.hiren.receiver.phone"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <receiver android:name="MyPhoneReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" >
                </action>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" >
    </uses-permission>

</manifest>

****Create the MyPhoneReceiver class.**** 

package com.hiren.receiver.phone;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyPhoneReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String state = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
            Log.w("DEBUG", state);
            if (state.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
                String phoneNumber = extras
                        .getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                Log.w("DEBUG", phoneNumber);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer Hiren. Unfortunately it cannot tell me, if there is more than one call active at a time, which is the primary thing I need to know with this check. It seems android will only tell me the state of the active phone call (the person im speaking to) but says nothing about the 10 persons I possibly have on hold. As I understand your answer, that code will tell me when the state of the active call changes, but still nothing about the remaining calls?